# Can I use MySql FULLTEXT search to find match using parts of strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm using MySql 8.0.  I have added this index to my table ...

```
ALTER TABLE directory_coop ADD FULLTEXT name_ftndx (name);
```

This seems to allow me to find data with certain words, e.g. this returns a lot of results ...

```
SELECT * FROM directory_coop WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('credit' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

but this returns nothing ...

```
SELECT * FROM directory_coop WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('cred' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Am I using the index wrong?  I would like to be able to index and search parts of my string.  I used to do this

```
SELECT * FROM directory_coop WHERE name like '%cred%';
```

but wanted to avoid the inherent performance issues.

Comment: `MATCH(name) AGAINST ('cred*' in BOOLEAN MODE`)`

Comment: Thanks, but this only works if "cred" is at the beginning of a word.  It doesn't work if it is in the middle of a word (I tried 'MATCH(name) AGAINST ('*cred*' in BOOLEAN MODE)' but to no effect)

Comment: Right, Full-text search can't do that, it's not indexed appropriately to make that efficient.

Comment: If you need to do that efficiently you have to find another database.